# Get array consisting of first values of a list of tuples

Tags: c#, list, loops, iterator, tuples

In my C# code I have a list of Tuples. The tuples themselves consist of two numbers of the type `double` and an object of type `LocalDate`.

```
List<Tuple<double, double, LocalDate>> tupleList = new List<Tuple<double, double, LocalDate>>();
```

The list, for instance, could look as follows.

```
1, 10, LocalDate1
12, 310, LocalDate2
31, 110, LocalDate3
```

What is an elegant way to create an array of doubles that only contains the first double values of each list item?

Accordingly, I want an ArrayList that only consists of the `LocalDate` objects in the list. The order should be preserved.

The expected result should be:

```
double[] => [1, 12, 31]
double[] => [10, 310, 110]
ArrayList<> => [LocalDate1, LocalDate2, LocalDate3]
```

I am aware that the ordinary way would be to iterate over the list in a for loop and create the arrays via this loop. However, I think that there should be a more concise and elegant way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq would be the way to go:

```
var firstValues = tupleList.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

This projects the list of Tuples into a list of the first items only, keeping their order. Same with the second, third, n'th item as well.
If you want an array, just invoke `ToArray()` instead of `ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get an `ArrayList`? Due to other code dependencies, I need exactly this typ.e

Comment: If you absolutely have to use `ArrayList`, there is a constructor with the signature [`ArrayList(ICollection)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ArrayList__ctor_System_Collections_ICollection_). So you can use it like: `ArrayList firstValues = new ArrayList(tupleList.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList()); `

Comment: Hm, that's strange. You could try passing the constructor argument as a named parameter: `new ArrayList(c: tupleList.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList());`, maybe this will force the compiler to use that specific constructor.

Comment: sorry, my bad (that's why I deleted my comment): I am working with ikvm (java to C# code migration) and the ArrayList class was actually the java.util.ArrayList, hence the confusion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped you please consider marking it as accepted with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a baseline for loop:

```
//Sorry for any Syntax errors. Got no VS installation in reach
double[] output = new double[tupleList.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < tupleList.Length; i++){
  output[i] = tupleList[i].Item1;
}
```

Of course something like linq or anything that uses lambdas in general might be more modern. But I doubt it is faster or more memory efficient. It has to use a List of some sort and create an array from that.